# Is it dangerous not to verify the signature of an id token issued by an external authorization server?

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

I need to retrieve some values from an id token issued by an external authorization server inside a private network.

I asked for the certificate used to sign the jwt in order to verify it but I've been told there is no need to do so. The main argument is that there is no threat of someone compromising the response of a request on a tcp/ip connexion, and thus the jwt can be trusted.

I am still not totally convinced given that the connexion is not using TLS/SSL.

What are the possible threats?

Answer (score 1):

As general rule, you should validate the signature on JSON Web Tokens whenever they are used, as this is the model of security around which they are built. There is absolutely no doubt that verifying the token is a better implementation, and even if the risk is low now, having verification in place will be a better security posture to build on for the future. Another developer down the road may assume you were verifying the token and that could cause a vulnerability even if there is not one now.

**Note:** Some of my opinion will be controversial to people who feel security should be absolute. I'm personally of the opinion that security needs also to be *practical* in order to be effective. You shouldn't spend $1000 on a safe to protect a $1 chocolate bar. But conversely, if you are dealing with valuable assets like financial information or personally identifiable information, you should certainly take appropriate precautions.

#### Risk

It is up to you in your implementation to determine whether it is worth the risk to skip verification.

- Are the fields you're retrieving for access control, or purely for informational purposes?
- Do you have alternate mechanisms in place to verify the token before this system accesses it?
- What are the risks involved if the token was forged? Information disclosure? Privilege escalation? Injury or loss of life? Inaccurate security log entries?

#### Transport Encryption

You mentioned that it is passing over the network without TLS. I presume that is on the internal network only. A lack of transport encryption on a private network is not ideal to say the least, but you'll again have to weight the risk factors of what the token is used for to decide if this is acceptable. It will also depend on whether you trust the other security controls applied on your network - which you probably shouldn't, but you could have very good network security engineers and still not being using TLS... I don't have that information.

If it is passing over the public internet without TLS you should not trust the token at all, as it may have been compromised.

Not having encryption in transit for security tokens does expose you to a whole range of threats related to spoofing, tampering, and information disclosure. IP networks route over multiple hops, and without encryption and digital signatures provided by TLS someone could - amongst other things:

- intercept the request before it gets to your 3rd-party authorization service and return an entirely forged token with more privileges
- intercept a valid token in transit and alter it to have more permission than it does
- steal the token in transit and inject it in requests to authorize other requests

#### Signature Verification and Secrets

Note also that HMAC signature methods use a pre-shared key rather than a public key for verification.

In your scenario, if an attacker stole the token you are handling, it would authorize them to do whatever that token can do. But if they managed to steal the pre-shared key, they could generate an HMAC signature for a token with any identity or permission scope in your system.

That's a risk as well, so if it's not actually essential to verify the token in your given context, it may actually be a reasonable measure to keep the shared key out of play to avoid the risk of exposure for the more valuable secret. It's all a balance of risk.

Note also that this risk does not exist for public-key or certificate-based signature methods. The key needed for verification in these cases is intended to be shared publicly and there is no risk associated with storing that information.

Comment: Two small notes: Risk assessment is not controversial, it is a best practice. HMACs are not signatures, using both together generates confusion, especially among those not versed in information security.

Comment: Fair on the signature point. How do you suggest I reword that? Digests? I just want to bring up that not all JWTs use the same algorithms and for some there may be valid reason not to spread around the material needed to verify.

Comment: I suggest you use "authenticity verification", because it is the common property of HMACs and signatures that is needed here. i.e., I would suggest rewording your answer to put less focus on signatures (which are just a mean to achieve a goal), and more focus on their security property.

Comment: Good way of putting it. I’ll be a few hours until I have some time to update my answer, but I will revisit with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to be worried. For a "Man-in-the-Middle" (MitM) attacker - that is, anybody on the same network as you and either physically positioned such that the network traffic flows through their device or logically positioned as part of the route (which can be done using things like ARP spoofing) - intercepting, modifying, and even forging TCP traffic is trivial. Without TLS or some other way to authenticate the network endpoints and protect the integrity of the traffic, you can never be sure that any network traffic you receive came from who you expected it to come from and/or hasn't been modified en route. This applies to sending data, too. (MitM can also see the network traffic, of course, unless you have some way to establish confidentiality - typically some encryption scheme - which is also part of TLS and most other network security protocols).

**If** the "external" server is connected to you via an entirely trusted connection - that is, no unknown device can connect to it, no part of it is sent over a connection vulnerable to physical tampering, and all of the devices on the network are fully trusted to not be malicious ("Only employee devices can connect" does *not* qualify; malicious insiders are a thing, and employee hardware can also get malware)… **then** trusting the JWT's claims is probably okay, though it's still a good idea to validate. If by "external" you mean anything like "is reached via the Internet" or "runs in the isolated network where we allow less-than-fully-trusted software / devices" then the claim "there is no threat of someone compromising the response of a request on a TCP/IP connection" is total BS and you should be ***extremely*** skeptical of the competence of anybody making it.

Also, there's just no legit reason to not give you the certificate. Certs are, by design, public. Even if the cert is self-signed or chains to a root you don't know about, it doesn't contain any secrets; just the public key, the validity period, the uses it's valid for, the identity it represents, and the identity of its issuer. The whole point of public key cryptography is that you can safely share the public keys (and their associated data), which is often done using an X.509 certificate. The only reason I can see for them to not want to share the public key (which is all you *really* need for signature verification) is if they rotate the key pair very frequently, which shouldn't happen and is itself a red flag about their key management (key rotation *must* be possible; it *should* be rare).

Comment: Just a side-note, I agree with everything said in this answer, despite my answer taking less focus on how trivial it is to compromise a network. My answer focused primarily on the risk associated with what the token gives access to. I also found it a little open to interpretation as to whether the JWT was fetched without TLS publicly, or whether it was being passed around on an internal network after TLS was terminated at a web server or load balancer, for example.

Comment: The fields I'm retrieving are for informational purposes only (so there is no threat of elevating the privileges), and both the authorization server and the gateway I'm dealing with are inside the private network ("external" was standing for "separated from the gateway").
My knowledge is limited but I was thinking of a MitM/spoofing threats.

Thanks a lot for your answers.